# ActiveRecord3 deadlock retry

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, deadlock

Are there any plugins for Rails 3 (or ActiveRecord 3) that replicate the old [deadlock_retry](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/deadlock_retry) plugin? Or, does that plugin still work with Rails 3?

Answer (score 10):

I didn't even know there was a plugin to do this :)

Here's what we use (but you have to wrap deadlock-prone queries in it yourself):

```
# Executes the given block +retries+ times (or forever, if explicitly given nil),
# catching and retrying SQL Deadlock errors.
def retry_lock_error(retries = 100, &block)
  begin
    yield
  rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
    if e.message =~ /Deadlock found when trying to get lock/ and (retries.nil? || retries > 0)
      retry_lock_error(retries ? retries - 1 : nil, &block)
    else
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a [transaction_retry](https://github.com/qertoip/transaction_retry)  gem which not only works with Rails 3+ but supports all major databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite). It is marketed as clean and well tested.

Comment: Hmm, last commit was June 2018, but prior to that it was June 2013. A 5 year window where nothing was done to the gem. I'm skeptical. Would love to hear if anybody has this solidly working in Rails 4+.

Comment: We're trying it on our Rails 4.2.11 app right now and it appears to work great. It has completely resolved our Deadlock issues we've been seeing during intensive, concurrent imports and doesn't seem to be causing any other issues as far as we can tell.

Answer (score 2):

[rails / deadlock_retry](https://github.com/rails/deadlock_retry)

"Deadlock retry allows the database adapter (currently only tested with the
MySQLAdapter) to retry transactions that fall into deadlock. It will retry
such transactions three times before finally failing.

This capability is automatically added to ActiveRecord. No code changes or otherwise are required."

Comment: re "This capability is automatically added to ActiveRecord" - trying to find source confirming this, google-fu failing me. Can you point me to a description of this in AR core?

Comment: I thin perhaps you misunderstood--- the gem referenced (rails / deadlock_retry) by the poster automatically adds this to active record