# How to avoid race condition in a rails model that records payments and running balance?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a simple model, `Payments`, which has two fields `amount` and `running_balance`. When a new `payment` record is created, we look for the `running_balance` of its previous payment, say `last_running_balance` and save `last_running_balance+amount` as the `running_balance` of the current payment.

Here are our three failed attempts to implement the `Payments` model. For simplicity, assume the previous payment always exists and `id`s are increasing as payments are created.

Attempt 1:

```
class Payments < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_validation :calculate_running_balance
    private
    def calculate_running_balance
        p = Payment.last
        self.running_balance = p.running_balance + amount
    end
end
```

Attempt 2:

```
class Payments < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :calculate_running_balance
    private
    def calculate_running_balance
        p = Payment.where("id < ?", id).last
        update!(running_balance: p.running_balance + amount)
    end
end
```

Attemp 3:

```
class Payments < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_commit :calculate_running_balance
    private
    def calculate_running_balance
        p = Payment.where("id < ?", id).last
        update!(running_balance: p.running_balance + amount)
    end
end
```

These implementations may cause race conditions in the system as we are using `sidekiq` to create payments in the background. Suppose the last payment is `payment 1`. When two new payments, say `payment 2` and `payment 3` are created at the same time, their `running_balance` might be computed based on the running balance of `payment 1` because it might be the case that when `payment 3` is figuring out its running balance `payment 2` has not been saved to the database yet.

In particular, I am interested in a fix that avoids the running condition. I am also keen on looking at other rails apps that implement similar payment systems.

Comment: I probably wouldn't store derived data. But, if I did, it would just be one, simple UPDATE query.

Comment: This sounds more a like a deficiency in the modeling.  I would consider if you should create something like a `Account` model which keeps track of the balance instead of creating a weird interdependency between payments.

Comment: @max unfortunately, we have to display a running balance along with each payment. Given thousands of payments, I don't see a way around this if running balance for each payment is not computed and stored.

Comment: Hi @Strawberry I would be happy to hear out an atomic UPDATE that does the job.

Comment: In which case, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** this is the first version, for an actually working approach, see below:

You can get rid of race conditions if you **lock the last payment** when calculating the last balance using [pessimistic locking](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pessimistic-locking). For this to work you always need to wrap creating the payments with transaction block.

```rb
class Payments < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :calculate_running_balance

  private
  def calculate_running_balance
    last_payment = Payment.lock.last
    self.running_balance = last_payment.running_balance + amount
  end
end

# then, creating a payment must always be done in transaction
Payment.transaction do
  Payment.create!(amount: 100)
end
```

The first query to get the last `Payment` will also lock the record (and delay further querying it) for the duration of the transaction that wraps it, i.e. until the moment the transaction is fully committed and the new record created. 
If another query meanwhile also tries to read the locked last payment, it will have to wait until the first transaction is finished. So if you use a transaction in your sidekiq when creating the payment, you should be safe.

See the above-linked guide for more info.

**Update: it's not that easy, this approach can lead to deadlocks**

After some extensive testing, the problem seems to be more complex. If we lock just the "last" payment record (which Rails translate to `SELECT * FROM payments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`), then we may run into a deadlock.

Here I present the test that leads to deadlock, the actually working approach is further below.

In all tests below I'm working with a simple InnoDB table in MySQL. I created the simplest `payments` table with just the `amount` column added the first row and the accompanying model in Rails, like this:

```sql
# sql console
create table payments(id integer primary key auto_increment, amount integer) engine=InnoDB;
insert into payments(amount) values (100);
```

```rb
# app/models/payments.rb
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Now, let's open two Rails consoles, start a long-running transaction with last record lock and new row insertion in the first one and another last row lock in the second console session:

```
# rails console 1
>> Payment.transaction { p = Payment.lock.last; sleep(10); Payment.create!(amount: (p.amount + 1));  }
D, [2016-03-11T21:26:36.049822 #5313] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-03-11T21:26:36.051103 #5313] DEBUG -- :   Payment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `payments`.* FROM `payments`  ORDER BY `payments`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
D, [2016-03-11T21:26:46.053693 #5313] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `payments` (`amount`) VALUES (101)
D, [2016-03-11T21:26:46.054275 #5313] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: INSERT INTO `payments` (`amount`) VALUES (101)

# meanwhile in rails console 2
>> Payment.transaction { p = Payment.lock.last; }
D, [2016-03-11T21:26:37.483526 #8083] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-03-11T21:26:46.053303 #8083] DEBUG -- :   Payment Load (8569.0ms)  SELECT  `payments`.* FROM `payments`  ORDER BY `payments`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
D, [2016-03-11T21:26:46.053887 #8083] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Payment id: 1, amount: 100>
```

The first transaction ended up with deadlock. One solution would be to use the code from the beginning of this answer but retry the whole transaction when a deadlock occurs.

**Possible solution with retrying deadlocked transaction:** (untested)

With taking the advantage of the method for retrying lock errors by @M.G.Palmer in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7427186/1544012):

```
retry_lock_error do
  Payment.transaction 
    Payment.create!(amount: 100)
  end
end
```

When a deadlock occurs, the transaction is retried, i.e. a fresh last record is found and used.

**Working solution with test**

Another approach that I [came across](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html) is to lock all records of the table. This can be done by locking the `COUNT(*)` clause and it seems to work consistently:

```
# rails console 1
>> Payment.transaction { Payment.lock.count; p = Payment.last; sleep(10); Payment.create!(amount: (p.amount + 1));}
D, [2016-03-11T23:36:14.989114 #5313] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-03-11T23:36:14.990391 #5313] DEBUG -- :    (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `payments` FOR UPDATE
D, [2016-03-11T23:36:14.991500 #5313] DEBUG -- :   Payment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `payments`.* FROM `payments`  ORDER BY `payments`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
D, [2016-03-11T23:36:24.993285 #5313] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `payments` (`amount`) VALUES (101)
D, [2016-03-11T23:36:24.996483 #5313] DEBUG -- :    (2.8ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Payment id: 2, amount: 101>

# meanwhile in rails console 2
>> Payment.transaction { Payment.lock.count; p = Payment.last; Payment.create!(amount: (p.amount + 1));}
D, [2016-03-11T23:36:16.271053 #8083] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  BEGIN
D, [2016-03-11T23:36:24.993933 #8083] DEBUG -- :    (8722.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `payments` FOR UPDATE
D, [2016-03-11T23:36:24.994802 #8083] DEBUG -- :   Payment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `payments`.* FROM `payments`  ORDER BY `payments`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
D, [2016-03-11T23:36:24.995712 #8083] DEBUG -- :   SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `payments` (`amount`) VALUES (102)
D, [2016-03-11T23:36:25.000668 #8083] DEBUG -- :    (4.3ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Payment id: 3, amount: 102>
```

By looking at the timestamps you can see that the second transaction waited for the first one to finish and the second insert already "knew" about the first one.

So the final solution that I propose is the following:

```rb
class Payments < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :calculate_running_balance

  private
  def calculate_running_balance
    Payment.lock.count # lock all rows by pessimistic locking
    last_payment = Payment.last # now we can freely select the last record
    self.running_balance = last_payment.running_balance + amount
  end
end

# then, creating a payment must always be done in transaction
Payment.transaction do
  Payment.create!(amount: 100)
end
```

Comment: Hi BoraMa, thanks for the reply. I have a question regarding the locking mechanism which was not mentioned in the guide. If another query also tries to read the locked last payment and it wait until the first transaction is finished, does it still get the latest last payment record?

Comment: Hi Zilin, you make a very good point with that question. I made some tests and came to a few problems and solutions, pls see my updated answer.

Comment: BoraMa, thanks for the elaboration. In fact, we have adopted your first solution and so far it works just fine. Meanwhile, I am trying to wrap my mind around your 1st test case. In this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans), deadlocks happen when two transactions are trying to lock two locks at opposite orders. I find it hard to apply the same logic to your test case. I would greatly appreciate if you can teach me how to reason about deadlocks in this case.

Comment: Zilin, frankly, I myself would love to understand fully what is going on here, because I don't. I think the deadlock behavior relates to the fact that MySQL locks not only the given record but in scenarios similar to this one also other records as well as "gaps" between them. See [here](http://goo.gl/m8aZj9) and [here](http://goo.gl/cgY1eO) for a deeper explanation. And perhaps, with this particular case (`order by id desc limit 1`) it can happen that the order of locking is not fully consistent. But we'd need some MySQL guru to confirm this as this is essentially a wild guess from my side :).

Comment: Just a follow-up. We have so far encountered few occurrences of deadlocks. As for our application, we use `sidekiq` to backfill the job when deadlock exception is thrown (similar to `retry lock error` in the post).